# translate file (model) located on BIM 360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I am planning to translate my objects located on bim 360 a couple of times per monther in order to retrieve the newest metadata of it because I am storing it on my local MYSQL and comper the project how far is going based on the time of the translation via forge. My problem that BIM 360 allows us to this operation (translate the file) once every month, but I need to do it minimum once a week :/
can I use [Model Derivative API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) in order to translate specific objects that located on bim 360 by using its own URN:
please note that I am using only 3-logged authentication

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you say BIM360 will allow you to translate the file once per month - BIM360 translate files automatically as soon as someone needs it. You may want to follow up on this with either your BIM360 account admin or the Autodesk Support team.

Anyway, to answer your other question, yes you can use the Model Derivative API on the BIM360 file Version object. Your need to the the Data Management API to retrieve your file from the Hub -> Project -> Folder(s) -> File -> Version.

Comment: hi Cyrille long time no see, thank you you are totally right :)